# Запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Сейчас на одном сайте прочитал статью, где предлагают везде ставить двоеточие. Примеры:

1. Откройте: полиция! / Осторожно: злая собака! / Внимание: розыск! (Если поставить запятую, то получается обращение к полиции, собаке и розыску). А может: Осторожно! Злая собака! / Откройте! Полиция!

Тихо: идет экзамен! (или) Тихо! Идет экзамен!

А если: Осторожно: окрашено!  (или)  Осторожно! Окрашено! (как правильнее ?)

2. Маша, познакомься: это моя сестра Таня. (или) Маша, познакомься, это моя сестра Таня.
3. Не спи: замерзнешь! (или) Не спи! Замерзнешь! (или) Не спи - замерзнешь!
4. Знакомьтесь, Джо Блэк. (Здесь тоже можно посчитать за обращение к Джо Блэку, но здесь нет обращения, а есть представление.).

Тогда, может лучше: "Знакомьтесь: Джо Блэк"

Но в названиях фильмов "Откройте, полиция" и "Знакомьтесь, Джо Блэк" стоят запятые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласна, что везде должно быть двоеточие, потому что вторая часть указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой:

Откройте (почему?): (потому что это)полиция! / Осторожно(почему?): (потому что там)злая собака! / Внимание(почему?):(потому что идёт) розыск!

```
  А может: Осторожно! Злая собака! / Откройте! Полиция!
   Осторожно! Окрашено! (как правильнее ?)
```

Правильнее всё-таки двоеточие. С двумя восклицательными знаками как-то нелогично, это знак больших чувств и громкости голоса.После "Осторожно" воскл.знак приемлем,а после "Злая собака" зачем? Мы её не зовём, не выказываем удивления от её появления, наоборот, предупреждаем о её появлении, а двоеточие как раз и есть знак ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЯ.

```
 Маша, познакомься: это моя сестра Таня. (или) Маша, познакомься, 
  это моя  сестра Таня.
```

Думаю, предпочтительно двоеточие, но запятая тоже возможна, если прочитать без интонации предупреждения.

```
         Не спи: замерзнешь! (или) Не спи! Замерзнешь! 
         (или) Не спи -   замерзнешь!
```

Все варианты возможны. 1-предупреждение. 2-два отдельных восклицания 3-оттенок противопоставления А ТО ЗАМЁРЗНЕШЬ

```
  Знакомьтесь, Джо Блэк.
```

Лучше: "Знакомьтесь: Джо Блэк"-интонация предупреждения и разъяснения.

А о фильмах - там не очень "заморачиваются" по поводу таких пунктуационных нюансов.Бывают и грубые ошибки.

Comment: Людмила, согласитесь, что двоеточие – это всё-таки "книжный" знак, и чем дальше, тем все более "книжным" он становится. "Осторожно: окрашено!" и тому подобные объявления с двоеточием выглядят очень странно. Главное ведь практика, вы много видите таких объявлений?

Comment: Запятая в некоторых примерах тоже выглядит странно. Вот ссылка: http://www.svetozar.ru/index/id/72464/index.html

Comment: По этой ссылке столько пунктуационных ошибок, что доверять такому "аффтару" – последнее дело.

Comment: Да и по сути тоже... "Самый умный знак препинания",  "показатель зрелости Личности" – этта што? Это называется "бойкое перо", больше ничего.

Comment: Хотя бы пару примеров пунктуационных ошибок ? А то, может быть, я на самом деле повелся?

Comment: После слова осторожно(,) по всем правилам пунктуации(,) полагается стоять Двоеточию. Хотя бы это.

Comment: Забавно, что в конце своего пассажа автор рекомендует справочники по пунктуации, и лучше Розенталя, у которого, разумеется, такой галиматьи и близко нет.

Comment: Какие есть официальные правила , которые запрещают ставить двоеточие во всех этих примерах?

Comment: Да не запрещают... Просто это выглядит слишком искусственно. Формально ошибки нет, просто так никто не пишет.